# oracle value exists in collection

Tags: collections, plsql, oracle11g, exists, oracle-type

I have function (used within a view) with the end result being a list of unique values from a row within a table of comma separated values.

Essentially given a table of:

```
studentid    classes
12345        MATH 1301, HIST 1301, POLS 1301
57495        MATH 2309, HIST 1301
39485        MATH 1301, HIST 1301
```

I want to see

```
MATH 1301
MATH 2309
HIST 1301
POLS 1301
```

The below code works perfect if the source table is small, but when looking at a table of 30,000 rows I get the following error. `ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit`

I'm pretty sure my problem is the collection is getting too large since it's getting duplicate values.  The duplicate values in themselves only become a problem when the collection becomes too large.  How do I keep the duplicate values out of the collection?

I've tried `childnames.exists(element)` but I believe this only works for seeing if there exists an element at the index value `element` correct? of I've looked at `member of` but I don't understand how to implement it..  Is there an easy way to check if a collection element exists?  Or am I over looking something simple?  Is there a different type other than `odcivarchar2list` that would allow a larger collection?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unique_values_from_csv ( p_del VARCHAR2 := ',')
   RETURN SYS.odcivarchar2list
IS
   childnames   SYS.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list ();
   tempvar VARCHAR2(255);
    l_idx    PLS_INTEGER;
    l_list2    VARCHAR2(32767) ;
    l_value VARCHAR2(32767);

   CURSOR tablewalker_cur
   IS
      SELECT distinct classes
        FROM studentclasses;

BEGIN
   FOR recordwalker_rec IN tablewalker_cur
   LOOP
   l_list2 := recordwalker_rec.classes;
      LOOP
         l_idx := INSTR (l_list2, p_del);

         IF l_idx > 0
         THEN

            childnames.EXTEND;            
            tempvar := (LTRIM (RTRIM (SUBSTR (l_list2, 1, l_idx - 1))));
            childnames (childnames.COUNT) :=  tempvar;
            l_list2 := SUBSTR (l_list2, l_idx + LENGTH (p_del));
           end if;

            childnames.EXTEND;
            childnames (childnames.COUNT) :=  (LTRIM (RTRIM (l_list2)));
            EXIT;

      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN childnames;
END unique_values_from_csv;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function unique_values_from_csv(p_del varchar2 := ',')
return sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll is
    childnames sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll();
    l_idx    pls_integer;
    l_list2    varchar2(32767) ;

    procedure add_if_not_member(new_element varchar2) is
    begin
        if new_element not member of childnames then
            childnames.extend;
            childnames(childnames.count) := new_element;
        end if;
    end;
begin
    for recordwalker_rec in (select distinct classes from studentclasses)
    loop
        l_list2 := recordwalker_rec.classes;
        loop
            l_idx := instr (l_list2, p_del);
            if l_idx > 0 then
                add_if_not_member(trim(substr (l_list2, 1, l_idx - 1)));
                l_list2 := substr(l_list2, l_idx + length(p_del));
            else
                add_if_not_member(trim(l_list2));
            exit;
            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;
    return childnames;
end unique_values_from_csv;
/
```

- Used SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL, which is a `TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000)` and should support any number of elements.  Although `l_list2 varchar2(32767)` will limit the results.
- `MEMBER OF` is the correct condition.
- Added an ELSE - the original function was only splitting the list in two.
- Removed the cursor - for such a small query, another level of indirection isn't worth it.
- Used TRIM() instead of LTRIM(RTRIM())
- The best solution would be to throw out this function and stop storing non-atomic data in your database.

Here's some sample data and a query using the function:

```
create table studentclasses(studentid number, classes varchar2(4000));

insert into studentclasses
select  12345, 'MATH 1301,HIST 1301,POLS 1301' from dual union all
select  57495, 'MATH 2309,HIST 1301' from dual union all
select  39485, 'MATH 1301,HIST 1301' from dual;
commit;

select unique_values_from_csv from dual;

COLUMN_VALUE
MATH 1301
HIST 1301
POLS 1301
MATH 2309
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct
  regexp_substr(classes, '([^,]+)(,\s*|$)', 1, occ, '', 1) as class
from
  studentclasses,
  (
    select level as occ
    from dual
    connect by level <= (
      select max(regexp_count(classes, ','))+1 
      from studentclasses
  )
)
where
  regexp_substr(classes, '([^,]+)(,\s*|$)', 1, occ, '', 1) is not null
order by 1
```

Comment: +1 Will probably work better than my solution.  Although for large amounts of data it seems to run much slower.  For example, if you take my sample data and insert the table into itself 10 times.

Comment: @jonearles - Yes, regexp operations are rather CPU-intensive.